# layer.cornerRadius not working in conjunction with NSLayoutConstraints (swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

Below are my profile view constraints and the view renders well, however the width consistently returns zero. So that final constraint, profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = (profile.frame.width / 2) returns zero everytime.

```
    profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: profileImageView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.125, constant: 0))


    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: profileImageView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.125, constant: 0))




    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: profileImageView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: profileImageView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 0.25, constant: 0))

    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = (profileImageView.frame.width / 2)
```

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: The profileImageView is likely not laid out yet. Try profileImageView.setNeedsLayout() before setting the cornerRadius. However, that might not actually update fast enough. From the docs "this method does not force an immediate update, but instead waits for the next update cycle"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`profileImageView.frame.width` is zero, because of it's frame isn't calculated yet. Inside your `profileImageView` override `layoutSubviews` method:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    layer.cornerRadius = bounds.width / 2.0
}
```

Or if you're using view controller, override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.bounds.width / 2.0
}
```

Comment: overriding layoutSubviews does not return any errors but the problem persists

Comment: @Stefan did you check frame of `containerView `?

Comment: I have included a screenshot of the application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143915/discussion-between-stefan-and-vasilii-muravev).

Answer (score 0):

`profileImageView` hasn't been laid out yet and doesn't have a size. Presuming this is in a `UIViewController` subclass, you can put the corner radius code inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = (profileImageView.frame.width / 2)
}
```